# Weird GPS latitude values

Tags: android, gps

App gathers gps location of the user and sometimes coordinates are without fractions digits, but it occurs only for latitude. For example:

- lon; -0.047041704120082115;    lat; 40.0
- lon -2.5132747513111577;       lat; 56.0

I thought that it is caused by some casting from double to int, but I double checked all the code, and there is no place with casting.

Is this possible that GPS, returns values with exactly 0, without any fraction digits or it has to be some problem in my code? Maybe the users are mocking location and this is the reason?

Comment: Are you using emulator or real device?

Comment: Real devices. I get this data from the real users, not from my device.

Comment: can u post the code...how u getting lat long...

Comment: LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context
           .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location location = locationManager         .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
double latitude = location.getLatitude();

Comment: If it is a real device, either it is a bug in your app, (unlikely) or a mocked location. for sure no real one, Please update when you found out.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible that GPS, returns values with exactly 0, without any
>   fraction digits or it has to be some problem in my code?

Practically that will never happen. If you get such values, more than one time in, let say ten thousand cases, then for sure the cause is a bug, testdata,  simulation or similar.